# Время в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Нужно вывести количество секунд в виде двухзначного числа (19:56:09)
Моя попытка это сделать:

```
var time = setInterval(function() {
Data = new Date();
  Sec = Data.getSeconds();
  if (Sec < 10) {
    return "0" + Sec
  }
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = (Sec);
}, 1);
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что не так?))

Comment: Data - данные. Date - дата

Answer (score 1):

Что такое `Data`? Вот и я не знаю)

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```js
var time = setInterval(function() {
    Sec = (new Date()).getSeconds();

    if (Sec < 10) {
        //return "0" + Sec
         Sec = "0" + Sec;
    }

    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = (Sec);
}, 1);
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Вместо условия можно `(''+Sec).padStart(2, '0')`

Comment: @entithat всегда есть что улучшать. Но вопрос был не в этом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский иногда новичкам нужно показать как лучше, чтобы они смогли это запомнить и применить в будущем.

Comment: @MoloF согласен, но вы, например, в своём ответе не написали почему это лучше и что это всё значит))

Comment: Извините,  уже исправил

Comment: @NetscapeNavigator Поправил ответ. Проблема в `return`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const date_element = document.querySelector('#date');

setInterval(() => {
    const seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
    date_element.innerHTML = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```